# Read mouse wheel USB Host HID on ESP32-S3

Tags: usb, mouse, esp32, hid

I'm testing the USB HID host examples, and so far, I've been able to read mouse data correctly. However, I was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to obtain mouse wheel data.

I appreciate any guidance or advice you can provide. Thank you!

Best regards.

Read mouse wheel on ESP32